# Replacing inherited final methods with jmockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jmockit

I'm trying to find a way to replace an inherited final method with my own implementation using jMockIt.

Lets say I have the following:

```
public class Base {
  ...
  public final int getX() {...}
}

public class Derived extends Base {
}
```

Is there a way that I can redefine getX() to always return 10 for example?

I tried doing something along the lines of this:

```
new Base() {
    @Mock
    public int getX() {
        return 10;
    }
};

Derived d= new Derived();

System.out.println(d.getX());
```

Which yields a runtime exception about jMockIt not being able to find a matching method for int getX().

I came across this thread:
http://groups.google.com/group/jmockit-users/browse_thread/thread/27a282ff2bd4ad96

But I don't quite grasp the solution provided there.

Anybody able to help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution...looks like I just had to mock the base class and the derived instances also got updated:

```
...
new MockUp<Base>() {
    @Mock int getX() { return 10;}

};
Derived d = new Derived();
System.out.println(plot.getWidth());  // prints 10
...
```

Comment: That's cool... I just wanted to say that you should be careful when using these mocking frameworks. They say that when all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail. Sometimes having to find solutions like this indicates that there is an interface missing in your design. Introducing a new interface that itself can be mocked might be something you want to do rather than mocking final methods. After all, that method is marked final probably for a very good reason.

Comment: I completely agree.  The problem is that in this case it's not my code; it's Google's.